# how to post JSON data to my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest

I'm am new to rails.  I want to consume my rest API with an android application. So I want to test whether my controller handles POST request or not. I'm using Advanced REST client for chrome to make a POST request.

Errors

> Bad request 400 - rest client (chrome)

Update 1:
Log output:

Started POST "/android" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-17 00:51:09 +0530
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

{tablet_id:1,pulse:2,pulse_timestamp:'NOW()'}

ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at '{tablet_id:1,pulse:2,pulse_timestamp:'NOW()'}'):

My rails controller:

```
class Android::PulseFeedbacksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pulse_feedback, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy]
  respond_to json
  # GET /pulse_feedbacks
  # GET /pulse_feedbacks.json
  def index
    @pulse_feedbacks = PulseFeedback.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @pulse_feedbacks }
      format.xml { render xml: @pulse_feedbacks }
    end
  end

  def create
    @pulse_feedback = PulseFeedback.new(pulse_feedback_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pulse_feedback.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pulse_feedback, notice: 'Pulse feedback was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pulse_feedback }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @pulse_feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pulse_feedback
      @pulse_feedback = PulseFeedback.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pulse_feedback_params
      params[:pulse_feedback]
    end
end
```

Comment: Your server log will have more information that tells you exactly what is happening (and possible what is wrong)

Comment: @JanHøjriisDragsbaek Server error is :Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

{pulse_feedback:{tablet_id:1,pulse:2,pulse_timestamp:'NOW()'}}                     Am I sending json data in wrong format?

Comment: You should update the question to contain the log output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [rails routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Specifically at the section where it defines the types of HTTP verbs created for a controller. By default the only `POST` is `:create`. But you can edit your routes to explicitly allow POSTs for your own custom APIs by changing Routes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

```
def pulse_feedback_params
  params.require(:pulse_feedback).permit!
end
```

But of course server log output will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys, after lot of head breaking got it working.
The problem was with my application_controller.rb and my json format above.

I had to comment this line

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in my application_controller.rb file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      respond_to :html, :json

      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
      protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
      #before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

It wasn't accepting POST request from unauthorized clients(as I was using a chrome-addon to make POST request)

And my json format should have been:

```
{
    "pulse_feedback": {
        "tablet_id": "1",
        "pulse": "2",
        "pulse_timestamp": "NOW()"
    }
}
```